# a php script that automatically sorts news into pages?

Tags: php, html

I am working on a news based website.The thing is I want my site to be like other news sites.in which the news have thumbnails and if there is no room for them,the older news would go to the next page!I just want to have a general idea about this.Is there some kind of programming behind this kind of work(that every time you want to add a news,the program automatically sorts it and give it a thumbnail)and or should the admin of the page(me in this case for example) rewrite the html file of the news?I hope I made my self clear enough about what I want to do!

Comment: [What have your tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: Yes, generally web sites have "programming behind" that does this, unless you want to hire an army of slaves to type in results on-the-fly.

Comment: Personally I would use a CMS like `Wordpress` if I did not have much programming knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you query the database you're going to want to `LIMIT` your query to a certain number results, and also set a start and an end to the query. See a tutorial [here](http://www.phpjabbers.com/php--mysql-select-data-and-split-on-pages-php25.html)

Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 0, 20";
```

When the `next` button is clicked, for example, your next query might look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 20, 20";  -- Start from 20, and take 20
```

You would use some server side language to keep track of where the query started and left off.

Comment: ok then.thanks.I've got the general idea.I haven't thought of using mysql for the news.so thanks again.

Comment: @user2078785 No problem, but you're going to have to use *some* query language to get the news article from *some* database

Answer (score 0):

It's called pagination, I suggest you do some reading on the subject.  No one is going to give you all the code, you seem to not know what you are doing.